# Status bar in titanium

Tags: ios, colors, titanium, statusbar

The new iOS 7 is quite tricky. I am having issues with the status bar color in my titanium iOS 7 simulator. I asked the question On titanium but the answer i got dint resolve the issue, i would want to change the status bar color to black.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know what the suggestion at the dev forum was, but this should do the trick:

```js
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    ...
    statusBarStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.OPAQUE_BLACK
});
win.open();
```

Make sure to

- set the statusBarStyle **before** opening the window, setting it afterwards is not supported in iOS7
- set the Titanium SDK to **3.1.3 GA** in tiapp.xml, as this is a new feature.

You can find the available statusBarStyles [in the docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar).
Moreover, [this link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_7_Migration_Guide) might shed some light on the changes in iOS7 and Titanium 3.1.3 SDK.

**Note**
This does not add a background color anymore, but only changes the text color. A workaround would be to add a 20px view to the top:

```js
var fakeStatusBar = Ti.UI.createView({
    left            : 0,
    top             : 0,
    height          : 20,
    width           : Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor : '#000'
});
win.add(fakeStatusBar);
```

Comment: thanks mwfire, my status bar text changed from black to white but the status bar color is not changed to black yet, i tried on my own but couldn't find solution. How can i get the status bar color to black.

Comment: Ah, I see, with iOS7 this only changes the text color, as there is no background for the status bar anymore. It is now part of the window. A workaround would be to add a black 20px view to your window...

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window statusBarStyle="Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.OPAQUE_BLACK" backgroundColor="#000">
```

gives me a nice black status bar with white text

Answer (score 0):

Just need to give your window's backgroundColor to black.

If you want to give some other color, and the labels to be white in color:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

in xml,

```
<Window id="contactScreen" backgroundColor="yourColor">
</Window>
```